# How to change href in django based on the current page url?

Tags: python, html, django

As I said in the title, what would be the correct syntax to change the href of a link according to the current url the user is on?

I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
{% if url == '' %} href='/cookies' {% else %} href='' {% endif %}
```

What would be the correct syntax to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the current url with

```
href="{% if request.path == '' %}/cookies{% endif %}"
```

Answer (score 1):

At Django 1.9 and above can use something like this

```
href='{% if not request.path %}/cookies{% endif %}'
```